# Would adding "always" and "possible" make this more readable?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

I just [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311324/656371) a question on the math exchange.

> The sum of each row is 1, whereas the sum of column is not.

about which I would like to improve some readability.

is the following one better? is it grammatical, idiomatic and more readable?

> The sum of each row is **always** 1, whereas the sum of column is **possibly** not.

Comment: First part sounds normal, but the second one, not so much (to me, at least). I would say something like *"...whereas the sum of each column might not be."*

Comment: Please try to make future titles shorter. Putting in an entire quote and then asking if it's more readable and grammatical is simply too much information in a title.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra Thanks, plz mv your comments to answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is perfectly fine, but second part sounds odd. Try to say like

> *"... whereas the sum of each column **might not be**."*

Answer (score 0):

It should be "always" an not "alway". You don't really need this word. You can say "The sum of each row is 1".

You would need to say that "the sum of each column is possibly not (1)"  However it is easier to rephrase.

> "the sum of each column could be any value"
>   "there is no restriction on the columns"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, there is restriction. those values must not be negative.

Comment: ... any positive value...